# Trouble using a sting variable instead of a literal in an EF query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have tried all the answers to similar SO posted questions and still haven't figured out what I am doing wrong when trying to use a variable in a query string in EF6 with Oracle. It works when I use a string literal and returns 1 record.

When I change the query to use a variable string the query returns 0 every time.

```
public PVI()
{           
    string MachineId = "M123";

    ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
    Encoder encoder = ascii.GetEncoder();
    encoder.Fallback = new EncoderReplacementFallback(string.Empty);

    //byte[] bAsciiString = ascii.GetBytes(MachineId);
    //string cleanString = ascii.GetString(bAsciiString);

    var utf8bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(MachineId);
    string cleanString = ascii.GetString(utf8bytes);

    PriorityNoteModel1 dbPriorityNote = new PriorityNoteModel1();
    var pnQuery = (from pn in dbPriorityNote.CNTR_SCHED
                // /*1. This works*/ where pn.WORK_CENTER.EQNO == "M123" & pn.CNTR_SEQ == 1
                // /*2. This does not work*/ where pn.WORK_CENTER.EQNO == cleanString & pn.CNTR_SEQ == 1
                   /*3. This does not work*/ where pn.WORK_CENTER.EQNO == MachineId & pn.CNTR_SEQ == 1
                // /*4. This does not work*/ where pn.WORK_CENTER.EQNO == Properties.Settings.Default.MachineId & pn.CNTR_SEQ == 1
                select pn).ToList();


    if (pnQuery.Count != 0) {
    }
```

All the code returns a count of 0 except for when "M123" is hard coded. I have tried converting to ASCII and all of the various UTF##.

Thanks
Jeff

Comment: Think you meant to use `&&` not single `&`?

Comment: I tried && and the results are the same.